# How do I make random choice from two options in haskell properly?

Tags: haskell

I want to write a function that would take a String and a Char and randomly either prepend or append the Char to the String.

I am wrote this, but it doesn't work because of some the type signature is the last line:

```hs
join :: RandomGen g => [Char] -> Char -> g -> ([Char], g)
join letters letter g = if inverse
                        then (letter:letters, newG)
                        else (letters ++ [letter], newG)
                        where (inverse, newG) = random g :: (Bool, RandomGen)
```

error i get:

```
• Expecting one more argument to ‘RandomGen’
  Expected a type, but ‘RandomGen’ has kind ‘* -> Constraint’
• In an expression type signature: (Bool, RandomGen)
  In the expression: random g :: (Bool, RandomGen)
  In a pattern binding:
    (inverse, newG) = random g :: (Bool, RandomGen)
```

So how do I properly generate a boolean value and return the new generator from the function?

Comment: What if you just withdrew the type signature on the last line ? RandomGen is a class constraint, not a type. And GHC would guess that the first component of the pair is a Bool, because it is an argument to the **if** construct. BTW you should be aware that `join` is the name of an important [library function](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.15.0.0/docs/Control-Monad.html#v:join).

Comment: 1) You don't need the type signature in the last line. 2) The proper signature would be `... :: (Bool, g)` where `g` is the same variable appearing in the outermost signature `jon :: ...`. 3) To tell GHC that we really want _that_ `g` we need to insist, enabling `ScopedTypeVariables` and using `join :: forall g . ...`. But, again, we don't really need to write the signature.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The type of `random g` is not <s>`(Bool, RandomGen)`</s> since `RandomGen` is a typeclass , not a type.

We can specify the type of `inverse` through a type application and thus implement this as:

```
{-# LANGUAGE TypeApplication #-}

join :: RandomGen g => [Char] -> Char -> g -> ([Char], g)
join letters letter g
  | inverse = (letter:letters, newG)
  | otherwise = (letters ++ [letter], newG)
  where (inverse, newG) = random @Bool g
```

That being said, since `inverse` is used by a guard (or `if … then … else …`) the compiler knows that `inverse` is a `Bool`, and thus it can work out the types for `inverse` and `newG`. It is thus sufficient to define `join` as:

```
join :: RandomGen g => [Char] -> Char -> g -> ([Char], g)
join letters letter g
  | inverse = (letter:letters, newG)
  | otherwise = (letters ++ [letter], newG)
  where (inverse, newG) = random g
```

It might also be better to use another name than `join`, since [**`join :: Monad m => m (m a) -> m a`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.15.0.0/docs/Control-Monad.html#v:join) is a function often used when working with monads.